# SQL multilevel join how to add a where condition

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following SQL query

```
    SELECT
    r.id as id,
    reports.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
    reports.Latitude as reportLat,
    reports.Longitude as reportLng,
    FROM Requests r
    LEFT JOIN 

    (SELECT 
      c.* 
    FROM
      PositionReports c 
      LEFT JOIN PositionReports d 
        ON c.RequestId = d.RequestId 
        AND c.Timestamp < d.Timestamp 
    WHERE d.RequestId IS NULL) reports

    ON r.id = reports.RequestId
```

So let's say the RequestsTable contains two entries, id's 178 and 179.

| id | otherdata |
| --- | --- |
| 178 | lorem.... |
| 179 | ipsum.... |

They both have matching rows in the positionReports table.

The PositionReports table contains

| id | requestId | applies | Latitude | Longitude | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 178 | 0 | 56.5 | 11.9 | 012345678 |
| 2 | 179 | 1 | 57.2 | 12.2 | 012345800 |
| 3 | 179 | 1 | 57.0 | 12.0 | 012345900 |

Desired output: the query should retrieve both requests, and pick the positionReport with the highest value in Timestamp. If the applies field is false, the position report should be ignored.

| requestId | Timestamp | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 178 |  |  |  |
| 179 | 012345900 | 57.0 | 12.0 |

I have tried every combination I could think of to insert a WHERE applies = 1 but I always end up with either no position report data or a duplicate of that request...

Is there even a way to place such a condition in there?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table being used.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use partitions when selecting rows based on lastest time. The following achieves your desired output.

```
select requestId,
case applies when 1 then Timestamp else null end as Timestamp,
case applies when 1 then Latitude else null end as Latitude,
case applies when 1 then Longitude else null end as Longitude

from (
select id, requestId, applies, Latitude, Longitude, Timestamp,
max(Timestamp) over(partition by requestId) as latest
from PositionReports
)

where Timestamp = latest;
```

The subquery selects PositionReports as normal, but also includes a column which has the latest timestamp for the given requestId.

The outer query filters the records where the timestamp matches this lastest this latest timestamp, and uses case on applies to display as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard row-numbering solution.

```
SELECT
    r.id as id,
    reports.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
    reports.Latitude as reportLat,
    reports.Longitude as reportLng,
FROM Requests r
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      reports.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY reports.RequestId ORDER BY reports.Timestamp DESC) AS rn
    FROM
      PositionReports reports
    WHERE reports.applies = 1
) reports
   ON reports.RequestId = r.id
  AND reports.rn = 1;
```

It's unclear if you want to filter out `applies` *before* taking the first `PositionReports` or *after*. If after then move `WHERE reports.applies = 1` to the outer level into the `ON`

```
   ON reports.RequestId = r.id
  AND reports.rn = 1
  AND reports.applies = 1;
```